# Using generic operator->* as rvalue

Tags: c++, templates, arm, iar

The compilation process of:

```
template <typename T> T GetMember(const T STRUCT_T::* member)
{
    STRUCT_T* pStruct = GetStruct();
    ...
    // read value
    T retVal = pStruct->*member; // compiler assertion here

    ReleaseStruct();

    return retVal;
}
```

ends due to compiler assertion when used with a non-basic type T:

> Tool internal error:
>   Internal Error: [Front end]: assertion failed at:
>   "....\Translator\compiler_core\src\parser\edg\lower_il.c", line 13411

Shocked by the fact that IAR compiler's "lower_il.c" has at least 13,411 lines and non of them is a proper generic operator->*(), I found it even stranger that the following function do compile with a non-basic type T:

```
template <typename T> void SetMember(T STRUCT_T::* member, const T& value)
{
    STRUCT_T* pStruct = GetStruct();
    ...
    // write value
    pStruct->*member = value; // no compiler assertion here

    ReleaseStruct();    
}
```

I guess the result of the generic operator is OK as lvalue but not as rvalue. Unconsting  the parameter didn't help.

Any ideas of cause and solution?

Comment: Short of upgrading the compiler, there are no "solutions" to internal compiler errors. The best you can hope for here is a workaround.

Comment: This looks like a parser error. Try something that does the same thing using a different syntax, for example `T retVal(pStruct->*member)`, `T& retVal = pStruct->*member`, or `const T retValPtr* = &(pStruct->*member)`. In short, do something to trick the compiler into taking a different path through the code, avoiding the assertion.

Comment: "T retVal = *&(pDbAppDynamic->*member)" worked. @dasblinkenlight Thank you so much.
I am still interested in knowing how this could have happened.

Comment: C++ compilers are enormously complex (13K lines is *not* a lot for a C++ compiler). Like most large programs, compilers have bugs, which should come as no surprise. You just happened to find one of them. If you could construct a small test case exposing it, e-mail it to the compiler manufacturer: given the ease with which you have found a workaround, this should be a simple fix for them.

Comment: I was not surprised about the compiler code size, but of the size of a single file. Maintaining, locating anything, version tracking, parallel team work and many other tasks are harder with larger files.

Comment: It is insanely rare for parser files to be maintained by hand these days: parser generators have been the norm for some forty years. Parser code generators produce a lot of code - I've seen ratios from 10:1 to 25:1, i.e. for each line of lex/yacc/antlr/javacc code you get 10 to 25 lines of generated C/Java/C#/etc. code. None of that generated code is maintained by hand, though: rather, a parser source is modified, and the generator is run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAR service pack 6.70.2 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can tell from `edg\lower_il.c` that this is the EDG frontend, not a proprietary IAR parser. EDG is well-maintained and well-respected, and you can play with a newer version at http://gcc.godbolt.org/ . (Select ICC from the compiler menu.)

The filename suggests that it's dealing with a lower-level intermediate representation, not building the initial AST. There may be a problem translating the pointer-to-member access to more primitive operations. Or the flag might be appearing on the wrong line. Internal errors aren't always precise. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be better.